# Get exact height of WinForms Font in pixels

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, fontmetrics

This is possibly a duplicate question, but I am unable to find the answer.

My only question is how to get height (ascent + descent, without any spacing) of the `Font` used in WinForms in pixels.
I have *Segoe UI 8.25 Regular* font.

`Font.Height` gives me 15 (pixels?)

I am able to get font metrics ans use `FontFamily`:

- `GetEmHeight` gives me 2048.
- `GetCellAscent` gives me 2210 (larger than EM?)
- `GetCellDescent` gives me 514

According to formula from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-obtain-font-metrics)

I should do following:

```
(ascent + descent) * font.Height / emHeight
which is
(514 + 2210) * 15 / 2210 = 19 pixels.
```

So:

- Calculating using MSDN's formulas gives me **19**px text height.
- `TextRenderer.MeasureText` for "Tg" string gives me **13**px.
- If a take a screenshot and measure it in Photoshop (from lowest bound of *g* to highest bound of *T*) i'll receive **10**px.

What I'm doing wrong and how this values are interconnected? The goal is to get something as closer as possible to screenshot's measuring results.

`TextRenderer.MeasureText` uses much of resources and I can't use it anytime during draw.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: To get pixels, you use conversion formula.

Comment: @Aybe just want to know the height of text for render calculations. If the text is definitely single-lined, there is no need to calculate the wordwrap (which is resource extensive) and the font's height is enough.

Comment: a) did you read about the internal leading? b) did you include anti-aliased pixel in your photoshop measuring? c) why do you worry about performance?? You can measure before drawing and use the pre-calculated data, no? d) you can also use a graphicspath's bounds to measure oly colored pixels..

Comment: You are using Font.Height where your reference is using Font.Size.

Comment: @TaW a) i don't need any internal leading. thats why i use `TextRenderer.MeasureText` instead of `Graphics.MeasureString` b) as I saw in photoshop, anti-aliasing is applied only in horizontal direction. and even if i add one pixel per each side, i should get 12px, not 19. c) I need.. to cache the Font height every time it is changed? It may work only as last chance hack. I don't need to measure strings in this case. I need only font's height..

Comment: @TnTinMn, thanks. It seems, that this is it. using `Size` gives 10.9px which is close enough to desired. This is the answer for what im doing wrong. You may write it as an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: It is the same as the answer from @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán, to whom you owe an apology for your comment to his answer.

Comment: The link makes a difference betqween internal and external leading; just want to point that out. Wow, you are right about anti-aliasing going only horizontally! Interesting..

Comment: Answer of @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán just references the article from MSDN I already read, while your answer points me on my mistake. Thats the difference

Comment: No, his answer shows using Font.Size.

Comment: Hmm. My question is "I used the formula from article and get wrong result. WTF?". He answers "use the formula from article". I don't think it is the answer for the question WTF:) Your answer is "you are using it incorrecly". This clearly answers for the question WTF.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with "Segoe UI" font family - using size 8.25 / regular style I get GetLineSpacing: 2724, GetCellAscent: 2210, GetCellDescent: 514 - you'll notice that LineSpacing = Ascent + Descent. So where has the gap gone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get pixels, you use conversion formula:

```
descentPixel = font.Size * descent / fontFamily.GetEmHeight(FontStyle.Regular);
```

From this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-obtain-font-metrics

Comment: Please read question carefully. I used that formula and get almost twice of required height. 19 px instead of 10